# Get unix timestamp exactly 3 years from now

Tags: android, unix-timestamp, android-date

Using Android and Java 8, how can I get unix timestamps back in time?

E.g.

- Exactly 3 years back from now
- Exactly 2 months back from now
- Exactly 1 day back from now
- etc

I know I can get current timestamp using `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L` (you could also use `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()` from the new *java.time*, but this requires Android API > 25). Now I need to get offset and substract it. I could use `TimeUnit.Days.toSeconds()`, but if I want to substract years, it does not have YEAR unit and I don't want to mess with leap years myself.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why you not use Calender class ? Just Curiosity.

Comment: Use the `Calendar` class (its [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) method with a negative value).

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya The terribly-designed `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Never use `Calendar` or `Date` again.

Comment: @BasilBourque so, what can you prefer ? Please post your answer.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157578/642706) by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this for getting timestamp using `Calender`....

> For After 2 month.

```
    Calendar date= Calendar.getInstance();
    date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);//instead of 2 use -2 value in your case
    date.getTimeInMillis();
```

> For after one day.

```
    Calendar date= Calendar.getInstance();
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);//instead of 1 use -1 value in your case
    date.getTimeInMillis();
```

> For after 3 years.

```
    Calendar date= Calendar.getInstance();
    date.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3);//instead of 3 use -3 value in your case
    date.getTimeInMillis();
```

**Note:- Use Negative value for back dates.**

Hope it solve your problems.

Comment: These terrible classes were outmoded years ago with the adoption of JSR 310, being supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Calendar`, `Date`, etc. See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157578/642706) by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    long threeYearsAgo = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .minusYears(3)
            .toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("Three years ago: " 
            + NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(threeYearsAgo));
```

When I ran this just now on my computer I got this output:

> Three years ago: 1,446,737,905

I am not completely sure what you get if today happens to be February 29 in a leap year; probably the same time of day on February 28 three years ago. If you need to be sure, check the documentation or try it out.

For months or days ago use the `minusMonths` or `minusDays` method of `OffsetDateTime`.

> the new *java.time* … requires Android API > 25

Not really: java.time has been backported.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [`OffsetDateTime.minusYears` documentation](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/OffsetDateTime.html#minusYears(long))
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;
setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*3)   // 3 days from now




 public void showDatedialog() {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DeliveryProduct.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c.getTime());
                        edDate.setText(date);
                        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;

        //dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(now+(1000*60*60*24*3));  //for 3 days from now
        Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
        d.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        //  dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(d.getTimeInMillis());
        dpd.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting unix timestamp one year ago from current time.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
long unixTimestamp = calendar.getTime().getTime() / 1000;
```

For month...

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```